# ATMega128 Operators

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, embedded, codevision

I'm using the ATMega128 micro for a project and CodeVisionAVR.  It seems as if when I try a += with 2 floats, it doesn't calculate properly.  For example, if I'm doing a PI loop for the integrator and do something like :

```
   float iTemp = 0;
   float countOffset = 0;
   iTemp += countOffset;
```

If I do that in my code, it gives very weird numbers that make no sense (expecting ~50, normally something like DC3D, but it changes everytime I print the numbers), I'm not even able to think of where they came from since they are inconsistant.  My main question, are you allowed to use the += operator with floats?

*Side note: What about a ++ with a float?

Comment: Please post the weird numbers, which you have mentioned.  Without those, the question is not quite complete.  What are the inputs?  What are the expected outputs?  What are the actual outputs?

Comment: So here is my actual code cut (hopefully pastebin works):
http://pastebin.com/UuTUHVKm

So I'm expecting a windup (should be slow, expecting values around 40-50).  However I get values like D3CD.  Whenever I print them, they always change.  Also, they are initialized to zero.  They are globals since it's an integrator accumulator.

Comment: @adeuerling Just edit the question.

Comment: What?? You are printing them as hex?? Floats have a little meaning in their hex representation.

Comment: Yup, it's not uncommon to print them in hex.  Cuts code out converting to decimal.

Comment: As I said, float as hex has a little meaning unless you know how to decode them from (presumably) IEEE-754 format. Given that, I believe the values are just fine.

Comment: 0xD3CD is only 16 Bits. Make sure you are not printing the 32 bit float as 16 bit int value.

Comment: It's an 8 bit micro, floats are 16 bit.  Good thought, I had that one too.

Comment: C `float` is 32 Bit on any compiler that I am aware of, including AVR.

Comment: Forget about the micro arch. You are dealing with standard C and it's types. `float` is not arch dependant. And it is easily provable by using the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: > Cuts code out converting to decimal.
If you use printf that code is already imported and linked into the application

Comment: @crasic We are on AVR bare metal 8 bit MCU. A single `printf()` call may actually bee too big for the tiny flash memory on some AVRs, because it links in too much C-lib stuff.

Answer (score 4):

1) `float` type is 32 bit long type, so if you really want to print it in hexadecimal representation, you should use the appropriate format specifier (or just examine the right number of bytes). 
2) floats are *usually* represented in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format in memory, so the HEX representation is not directly translating to the actual float value, so it may seem random. 
3) The arithmetical operators you have mentioned work just fine with floats.

*To find out the size of a type in bytes use the `sizeof` operator.